App crashes when click on audio in IMG.Ly VE.SDK
Error which i am getting when click on audio and app crashes:
D/FeatureFactory(14631): loadFeature() : android.widget.OverScroller$SplineOverScroller@959961b,ly.img.android.pesdk.ui.activity.ImgLyActivity$ImgLyContextThemeWrapper@d1722a
D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl(14631):
initSplineOverScrollerImpl: mScrollerVelocity is 0, value is 0
D/AndroidRuntime(14631):
Shutting down VM
W/sheesX.Frenzon(14631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(14631)
Using this function it work on IOS:
void _stopRecording() async {
setState(() {
  isRecording = false;

});
recordingTime.value = 0;
final XFile video = await _controller!.stopVideoRecording();
// Access the file path from the XFile
final videoPathss = video.path;
_recordingTimer?.cancel(); // Stop the recording timer
if (videoPathss == null) return;
try {
  await VESDK.unlockWithLicense("assets/vesdk_license");
} catch (error) {
  print("Failed to unlock VE.SDK with: $error.");
  return;
}
// Open the video editor and handle the export as well as any occurring errors.
final result = await VESDK.openEditor(Video(videoPathss));

if (result != null) {
  // The user exported a new video successfully, and the newly generated video is located at     `result.video`.
  print('result.video ${result.video}');

  print('result.video ${result.video}');
  File tempFile = File(Uri.parse(result.video).path);

  File MyFile = File((await getTemporaryDirectory()).path+"1.mp4");
  print('ddd');
  await MyFile.writeAsBytes(await tempFile.readAsBytes());
  _controller!.dispose();
  Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => VideoPlayerWidget(videoUrl: MyFile,),
    ),
  );
} else {
  // The user canceled the editor.
  // Handle accordingly.
}

want to add soundstripe songs in img.ly audio VE.SDK
want to open audio in img.ly VE.sdk also want my song from sound stripe in this .
App crashes when click on audio also i want sound stripe songs in img.ly
